# carriage Return regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

Im trying to match a carriage return in a .net regular expression so that we can replace it with a linebreak html tag
we currently have:

```
public readonly static Regex CarriageReturn =
        new Regex(@"^\r*$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

and then use it as:-

```
StandardRegexes.CarriageReturn.Replace("xxxxxxxx", "<br/>")
```

this is currently not matching correctly

any advise would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and check if it works:

`\r(?!\n)`